# Get the controls (UIButtons) and their tags of a UITableViewCell in a separate method

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I have a UITableViewCell in which I'm creating some buttons (which are acting like radiobuttons) and assigning tags to the buttons. But the tags are not static. They are dynamic. Now when a particular radiobutton is clicked I need to set that button with some image (radio_On.png) and remaining all buttons as (radio_Off.png). But to set the images I couldn't understand how to get the tag values of all buttons in that particular cell because they are not static.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    btTemp1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblQuestion.frame.origin.y+lblQuestion.frame.size.height+3,17, 17)];
    [btTemp1 addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btTemp1.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [btTemp1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btTemp1 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btTemp1.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];

    btTemp1.tag=++Optionid;
    [hlcell.contentView addSubview:btTemp1];

    btTemp2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, lblOption1.frame.origin.y+lblOption1.frame.size.height,17, 17)];
    [btTemp2 addTarget:self action:@selector(radioButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    btTemp2.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    [btTemp2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btTemp2 setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btTemp2.titleLabel.font =[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.f];

    btTemp2.tag=++Optionid;
    [hlcell.contentView addSubview:btTemp2];
}

-(IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)
    [[sender superview] superview]];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *cellSection = [self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-On.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Here one radiobuttton is not getting released when I check other button in TableView cell.

EDIT:

Prevoiusly I gave this code:

```
-(IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
        NSLog(@"%d", [button tag]);
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)
        [[sender superview] superview]];

        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSMutableArray *cellSection = [self.finalarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

UIButton  *btnTemp1 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:10]; //Static .But now I want dynamic
        UIButton  *btnTemp2 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:11];//Static .But now I want dynamic
        UIButton  *btnTemp3 = (UIButton*)[cell viewWithTag:12];//Static .But now I want dynamic
        UIButton *btnTemp4=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:13];//Static .But now I want dynamic
        UIButton *btnTemp5=(UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:14];//Static .But now I want dynamic

        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp1];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp2];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp3];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp4];
        [radioButtonsinaSection addObject:btnTemp5];


    }


    for(int i=0;i<[radioButtonsinaSection count];i++){

        [[radioButtonsinaSection objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio_button_off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"radio-On.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

How can I get the all the controls (buttons and their tags) of a cell in which button (radiobutton) is clicked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge you miss the loop in radioButtonClicked method,which keeps track of which button is clicked..you try this code..

```
   (IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender{

               for(int i=0;i&amp;lt;[self.radioButtons count];i++){
                       [[self.radioButtons objectAtIndex:i] setImage:[UIImage    
                                   imageNamed:@&quot;radio-off.png&quot;]  
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
               }
               [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@&quot;radio-On.png&quot;]   
                                     forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I think it helps you,if not feel free to ask again..

Enjoy..

Comment: Can u tell me where  is self.radioButtons created?I guess it is array which tells no of radiobuttons in a section...But how to create it and where?

Comment: @arizah radioButtons has been created in class..not in the method..in .h and .m of your class.so,try it..& let me know..

Comment: Sorry I didn't get u..I have created buttons(radiobuttons) in .h itself and used them in cellforrowatindexpath.But how to get the radiobuttons(ex.4 or 5)(with tags:not static) of a paticular section? in this method:   (IBAction) radioButtonClicked:(UIButton *) sender{
?

Comment: Prevoisly I gave static tags while creating radiobuttons.But now Im giving them like ++OptionId.So I don't know the tags of buttons in a particular section...

Comment: @arizah   i got you..wait i will send you the project copy which works for any number of radio button..

Comment: i am giving you a link just download source code from there..http://mobisoftinfotech.com/iphone-uibutton-tutorial-radio-buttons/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27925/discussion-between-arizah-and-json)

Comment: @arizah I was checking your code but getting nil response from server why??

Comment: Hey thers some problem with the url and its not working.I will let u know when it works......